# What will happen if I use setState() function in constructor of a Class in ReactJS or React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Out of curiosity, I just wanna know what will happen if I use `setState()` function in constructor of a Class in React Native or ReactJS?
Such as:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.setState({title: 'new title'});
}
```

what's the lifecycle of React gonna happen?

---

I haven't read the code inside React. I am afraid it will some any damage when I write it that way.

Comment: Try it out: put a `console.log()` message in each of the [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) and let us know.

Comment: Try it and see, thats the only way you'll know ;)

Comment: Might even say that `this.state` is for read-only, while `this.setState` is for writing updates.

Comment: Any genuiene reason(in other wordsthan given in doc) why super() used in constructor.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

What `setState` essentially does is to run a bunch of logic you probably don't need in the constructor.

When you go `state = {foo : "bar"}` you simply assign something to the javascript object `state`, like you would any other object. (That's all `state` is by the way, just a regular object local to every component).

When you use `setState()`, then apart from assigning to the object `state` react also rerenders the component and all its children. Which you don't need in the constructor, since the component hasn't been rendered anyway.

Comment: what if I have a promise inside of my constructor which manipulates the state on resolving. Would I set the state within the promise's callback as `this.setState`?

Comment: then u will have to use setState if you want to render again... But I find the render() function DOES run twice, but state is still default without the new values...

Comment: if you need to use promise inside constructor - Don't.
Instead, call the promise (for example a fetch call) inside `componentDidMount()` .

Answer (score 37):

Error Message would be
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'VARIABLE_NAME' of null`

Please see the following two jsfiddle snippets.

Case 1) [Working solution jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ldong/buwmyc66/2/)

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        name: 'world'
      } 
    }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.name} </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Case 2) [Not working solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ldong/buwmyc66/3/)

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.setState({
        name: 'hello'
      });
    }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.name} </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

This happens:
-constructor (starts setState)
-render (fails - because state has no property 'name' yet)
-name is added to state (but too late - it has already rendered)

Conclusion:

**My rule of thumb**, inside `constructor` uses `this.state = {}` directly, other places use `this.setState({ })`;

Comment: I observed this even in React Native. Wondering whats the reason behind it?

Comment: The idea is actually quite simple. Since `this.state` itself is a plain object, changing its value won't notify any listeners by default. Instead, `this.setState` is a function call, you can actually notify and dispatch events to other listeners. You can see `React` actually put the callback in a queue and do more optimization in the `setState` -> [ReactBaseClasses](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/e452e3374135c116ef687a8bb3a5d277e3cde8fb/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactBaseClasses.js#L68)

Comment: I was wondering why this.setState can't be called in constructor.

Comment: Because `setState` is async. It can result unexpected behavior if you were trying to get or modify `this.state` in the following life cycles, since `this.state` is not set yet.

Comment: That is the error that you get, but you don't say why you get it. I already know the error (or can at least find it, by running the code myself), I don't need to look up **what** error I'm getting. I'm looking it up, to understand **why**, I'm getting this error, and what might the creator's thinking behind this, be. I understand you **are** answering the question, but for future people, looking for an answer, it'd be much more helpful to explain the *why*, and not just the *what*.

Comment: my question is why setState() can be called in constructor but in render() it is still null!

Answer (score 5):

**Constructor**: Constructor is Used to initialize the state.

**State** : Components that contain local state have a property called "this.state".

**SetState**: React components have a method available to them called setState Calling "this.setState" causes React to re-render your application and update the DOM.you can also track of prevstate in setState
          If you use setState in constructor you would get error like this:Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component.

Answer (score 3):

React have not restricted the use of setState in any lifecycle event.
[React official docs link for state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

It was told that you cannot access state directly outside constructor .
So you are free to call setState anywhere .

Technically setState is meant to update the existing state with some new value passed within ,which react react handles in the next update cycle through batch process,so using console.log of state right after setState will give the stale value.

Now lets focus on what if we call setState in the constructor .
React will prepare the batched piece of code with the new state passed into the setState and trigger a update .

While react have not stopped you from doing this ,however it knows that doing so might land you up in trouble so leaves a nice message for you

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the  component.

React proceeds with further loading of component but the update never reflects for this batch.

So conclusion : If you try to do so you might not end up with error ,but you will have to bear the undesirable behavior as these updates will reflect no where even if triggered .

Comment: "so if incase you try to update some new value in setState which is not there in state already then it troughs a null check"
This is wrong. It fails because name is not set in the first render!

Comment: Oh Yes , Sorry my mistake . Editing the answer .