# React sharable panel url

Tags: reactjs

Consider my following snippet. Right now on button click it opens a div-three that loads AnotherComponent.The url is simply 'http://localhost:3000/de' i.e. Indexroot

What I want to achieve is: If I hit 'http://localhost:3000/de/?open' then I want the panel i.e. div-three already open.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            
            showThird: false
        }

        this.showDivThree = this.showDivThree.bind(this)
        /*if(props.location.search=="?open"){
            this.showDivThree()
        }*/
    }

    showDivThree() {

        this.setState(prevState => ({ showSecond: false, showThird: !prevState.showThird}))
        console.log(this.state)
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
       <div className={'wrapper' + ( this.state.showThird ? ' show' : '')}>

                <div className="one">one
                    

                    {/* Show third */}
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivThree}>{this.state.showThird ? 'hideThird' : 'showThird'}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="three">three
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivThree}>{this.state.showThird ? 'hideThird' : 'showThird'}</button>
                        
                        <AnotherComponent />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
    )
  }
}

class AnotherComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {   
            
        }
       
    }

  
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
        <h4>Another component</h4>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.one, .two, .three {
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #787567;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: border 0.2s, padding 0.2s, width 0.2s;
  min-height: 50vh;

}

.one {
  width: 100%;
}
.two {
  border-width: 2px 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 0;
}

.three {
  border-width: 2px 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 0;
}

.show .one, .show .two, .show .three {
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I have commented a code where I read search string from props.location, if it is present then I simply call the function that opens the div-three. But as I have mixed conditions to open divs it somehow is not working.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `setState` (`showDivThree` method calls `setState`) in `contructor` since when constructor is called component hasn't been mounted yet. Please check this  [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961853/what-will-happen-if-i-use-setstate-function-in-constructor-of-a-class-in-react) for more details.
You should move `if` statement checking URL search string from `constructor` to `componentDidMount` method which is called immediately after a component is mounted and in which you can safely use `setState`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showThird: false
        };

        this.showDivThree = this.showDivThree.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (props.location.search == "?open") {
            this.showDivThree();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Besides, I think that your URL should be without slash before search query. So it should be `http://localhost:3000/de?open` instead of `http://localhost:3000/de/?open`.