# Unable to bind 'this' when passing a function as props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My `Letter` component needs to be reused multiple times, with minor changes in what happens in its constructor. My idea was to pass a function as props to `Letter`, so I can call it in the constructor. However, I'm having a problem with `this`.

In the code below, when I invoke `this.props.setMessage.call(this)`, `this` refers to `Container` and not `Letter`, and so the state of `Letter` remains unchanged. I can see that `this` refers to `Container` by inserting `console.log(this)` in the body of the `setMessage` function in `Container`.

How do I bind `this` such that the state of `Letter` will change when I run this code?

Source:

```
export class Container extends React.component {

    ...

    setMessage = () => {
        this.state.message = 'hello';
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Letter setMessage={this.setMessage} />
            </div>  
    }
}

export class Letter extends React.component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.setMessage.call(this); // doesn't work, 'this' should refer to Letter but refers to Container
    }

    render () {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you are updating the state in a wrong way, use setState for that: `this.setState({message: 'hello';})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're using an [arrow function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Arrow functions immediately and permanently bind to the lexical context. Or to put it simply in this case, `this` will *always* be a Container.

To fix this, simply define it as a normal function.

```
export class Container extends React.Component {
  ...
  setMessage() {
    // As Mayank Shukla pointed out, this is how you should change state
    this.setState({ message: 'hello' });
  }
  ...
}
```

In general, `setState` is the correct way of updating state. However, if you try to use `setState` immediately in the constructor then [you will get an error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961853/what-will-happen-if-i-use-setstate-function-in-constructor-of-a-class-in-react)

So just know that if you're setting that state *anywhere* but the constructor, `setState` is the right way of doing so. In the constructor, you should assign the initial state directly, as you were doing before.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much, I'd been struggling to figure out what was wrong all morning.

Comment: @aethos Glad I could help!

Comment: In OP's code `setMessage` is being called from the constructor, which is the only place where you can assign `this.state` directly. I'm not 100% sure but I think calling `this.setState` in a constructor (or a sync function called by the constructor) results in an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961853/what-will-happen-if-i-use-setstate-function-in-constructor-of-a-class-in-react

Comment: @JordanRunning Very good point. Thanks for bringing it up. I'll update my answer to include information about that.

Comment: I thought I had it working for a while, but now it looks like I'm getting a new error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property state, object is not extensible`. This happens on the line where I'm trying to do `this.state = { ... }`, which seems to imply I can't modify `this`? On the other hand, `this.setState()` does not work, as you said...

Comment: @aethos Sounds like you're freezing that object at some point. I couldn't point you to the issue because in a standard setup, that error doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export class Container extends React.component {

    ...

    setMessage() {
        this.setState({
            message: 'hello'
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Letter setMessage={this.setMessage} />
            </div>  
    }
}

export class Letter extends React.component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }

    setMessage() {
        this.props.setMessage();
    }

    render () {
        ...
    }
}
```

"this" binds to the immediate scope when used in arrow functions
Also, prefer to use this.setState over this.state. = ...