# React state is null after redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am very new to React and using Redirect, and I am trying to implement a simple two-page app using React-Router. I was wondering how to initialize the state of a component after redirected to it. For example, I have the following View component that is being redirected to from another page:

```
class View extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({
      name: 'NAME'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <p>Hello {this.state ? this.state.name : 'null'}<p>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

The above component renders `null` after being redirected to from another page rendering `<Redirect to="/View">`. There is probably something subtle that I am missing here, but how would I properly initialize the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `setState()` in the constructor - the component is not yet mounted at this point in its life-cycle. See, for example, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58553414/1179377).

Instead:

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'NAME'
    };
  }
```