# Named function causing error with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my App class

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { lat: null, errorMessage: "" };

    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude });
    });
  }
```

When i change the arrow function to use the word function it throws me an error saying cannot read property of setState of undefined

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { lat: null, errorMessage: "" };

    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude });
    });
  }
```

Is something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961853/what-will-happen-if-i-use-setstate-function-in-constructor-of-a-class-in-react

You need to put this call in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow functions do not have their own `this` or context but use the context from the wrapping closure. In your case that context becomes the context of class and hence its able to use this.setState

In the second case, without the use of arrow function the context inside the function is received from where it is called. Since its a callback to `getCurrentPosition`, it received the context on window and setState is not defined on window. Which is why it breaks for you

Answer (score 1):

The context is different, that is not part of React, it is more just related to javascript.

traditional `function` will use the `this` of the caller (usually the event trigger)

However, arrow function will use the `this` from the current function context, in this case is the react component, that's why it works on arrow function.